# Substring comparision with std::memcmp or string::compare?

Tags: c++, string, c++14, c++17

I want to find a given string within another string. Possible start poisition in known by previous calculations. Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::string input("Foo Bar Hash Bang");
    std::string keyword("Bar");

    const char* inputStart = input.c_str() + 4; // at 'B'
    std::cout << "memcmp=" << std::memcmp(inputStart, keyword.c_str(), keyword.length()) << "\n";

    std::cout << "compare=" << input.compare(4, keyword.length(), keyword) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/LcoDwA)

Are both equivalent? If the keyword length would exceed the input length from the start position the comparision with `memcmp` would be still correct. Is `strncmp` the safer approach?

Comment: Why don't you use the find() method provide by the std::string?

Comment: @Oz. Performance. At that point I already know the position and length of the possible keyword. With find() I would have to call find for every keyword on the whole input string. An input string might not have a keyword at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe, and redundant, as `std::char_traits<char>::compare` anyway uses `memcmp` on most of the standard library vendors (I checked VC++ and GCC, which uses `memcmp` and `__builtin_memcmp` respectively) .

so as for performance - it won't change much.

better stick to `std::string::compare`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view):

```
bool matchSubstring(std::string_view haystack, 
                    std::string_view needle, 
                    std::size_t pos)
{
    if(haystack.size() < pos + needle.size()) return false;
    return haystack.compare(pos, needle.size(), needle) == 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::string input("Foo Bar Hash Bang");
std::string keyword("Bar");

std::cout << std::boolalpha << matchSubstring(input, keyword, 4) << "\n"
                            << matchSubstring(input, keyword, 5) << "\n"
                            << matchSubstring(input, keyword, 1000) << "\n";
```

> true false false

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ueaLtuLDnwWHSSFS)

Comment: I like the use of a new C++17 feature. Shouldn't substr() already take care of the over flow possibility? The substring would be shorter and not match. On the other hand substr() always creates a copy. I'll have to test it first.

Comment: [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/substr) creates a new `string_view` - that should be cheap. It also throws if the values are out of range, thats why I'm explicitly checking for it.

Comment: Also, I just updated the answer to use `compare` instead :)